# Swing: Characters not displaying on screen

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, keylistener

I am trying to display characters entered using keyboard. Here is my program:

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CenterJPanel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener, KeyListener
{
protected static int circleSize 20;
private int lastX = 0, lastY = 0;
protected static int recordX;
protected static int recordY;

public CenterJPanel()
{
    setBackground(Color.gray);
    JLabel jl = new JLabel("CENTER");
    this.add(jl);

    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
 }

 @Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{
    int x = e.getX();
    int y = e.getY();

    drawLine(x, y);
}

private void drawLine(int x, int y)
{
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2D.setColor(Color.Black);
    g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(circleSize));
    g2D.drawLine(lastX, lastY, x, y);
    record(x, y);
}

protected void record(int x, int y)
{
    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;
}
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{

    String s = String.valueOf(e.getKeyChar());
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 2));
    g.drawString(s, lastX + 10, lastY + 10);

    System.out.println(lastX + " " + lastY + "    String: " + s);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}
}
```

As you can see I can am overriding the `keyTyped`function but it does not seem to do anything. Please somebody help!

Comment: `getGraphics()` is not how painting should be done, apart from the fact that it can return `null`, anything painted to it will be wiped clean on the next paint cycle. Start by having a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for a better understanding of how painting works and how it should be done

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

A KeyEvent is dispatched to the component with focus. By default a JPanel is not focusable so it will not receive KeyEvents.

Try adding the following to the constructor of your class:

```
setFocusable(true);
```

If this is the only panel in your frame then it should gain focus.

Comment: I have tried that, however it did not work. I have a total of 4 panels attached to the Jframe.

Comment: @therimovie2ATmail.com, so you need to add the KeyListener to the component that has focus.

Comment: @therimovie2ATmail.com Only a single component can be focusable at a time, you can force focus by calling `requestFocusInWindow`, but I tend to do that on a mouse event to be sure